# Hiding a specific row of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am working on a todo list application with CoreData + UITableView, I would like to hide the row that the user mark as done.

My current solution is invoke deleteRowsAtIndexPaths when user mark the task done and deduct the deleted row from the function of numberOfRowsInSection.

```
-(void)markDone:(NSIndexPath *) _indexPath{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:_indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    deletedCount = deletedCount + 1;
    [self.tableView endUpdates];    
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    if (deletedCount>0) {
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]-deletedCount;
    }

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Although this method does work, but I do need some code hacking here and there. Is there a way to invoke NSFetchedResultsController didChangeObject for changing of status of particular field?

Thanks

Comment: seems correct to me, did you consider using two lists for your data, one for all and one for the ones which have not been marked as done?

Comment: Would prefer single list. I not too sure how to have two list with core data either. lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are many ways to solve this. I'd just add a field in your managed object which states if a row is hidden or not"

Deleting will set this field accordingly.

What you need now is an NSFetchRequest with the corresponding predicate to filter hidden rows.

I just created a simple template app with core data support, and I think it is very easy to achieve:

I added a hidden BOOL property to the one entitiy given, with default NO.

Then I added this code to didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
    [selectedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"hidden"];
}
```

In `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {...` I added

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hidden == NO"]; 
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

after

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
```

This was it to hide cells by clicking(just for this example) on them.

Comment: Thx for reply. I can query the data again, but I would love to show the row fade effect. That's why I am figuring how would I invoke NSFetchResultController didChangeObject with action of NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete. Do we have way to invoke didChangeObject function by changing field of the row (e.g. setting done=1)?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Nick! Now I get the idea.